# What do they mean by the sentence "is used to identify the subject of an elaborated-type-specifier" in [dcl.typedef]/8?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[dcl.typedef]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#8)

A *simple-template-id* is only a *typedef-name* if its *template-name* names an alias template or a template *template-parameter*.
[Note 1: A *simple-template-id* that names a class template specialization is a *class-name* ([class.name]). If a *typedef-name* **is used to identify the subject of an *elaborated-type-specifier*** ([dcl.type.elab]), a class definition, a constructor declaration, or a destructor declaration, the program is ill-formed. — end note]

[Example 8:

```
struct S {
    S();
    ~S();
};

typedef struct S T;

S a = T();                      // OK
struct T * p;                   // error
```

— end example]

I presume the sentence highlighted above explains the error. But I'm not sure I understand what do they mean by that sentence.

Comment: An _elaborated-type-specifier_ is simply a type with the keyword `struct` or `class` (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier).

Comment: Presumably, the "subject" is the type to the right of `struct` (`T`, that is). In other words, `struct T` is only valid if `T` is an actual class/struct, and not a typedef for one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are right. If I replace `struct T * p;` by `T * p;` the code compiles. Thank you.